# HTML put canvas on top of button

Tags: html, button, canvas

There are lots of "how to put a button on top of a canvas" articles, but I'm trying to do the inverse, a canvas sized to 100% of the button size that I set to transparent and draw stuff over the button using Javascript.

I have a row of buttons

```
.mainbut
{
    width: 8.5vw;
    height: 6.5vh;
    border: 0.25vw solid white;
    border-radius: 0.5vw;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.4vw;
    opacity: 1;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    margin-top: 0vh;
    margin-bottom: 0vh;
}


<div>
    <button class='mainbut' id='main1'  onclick='Main(1)'></button>
    <button class='mainbut' id='main2'  onclick='Main(2)'></button>
    <button class='mainbut' id='main3'  onclick='Main(3)'></button>
    <button class='mainbut' id='main4'  onclick='Main(4)'></button>
    <button class='mainbut' id='main5'  onclick='Main(5)'></button>
    <button class='mainbut' id='main6'  onclick='Main(6)'></button>
    <button class='mainbut' id='main7'  onclick='Main(7)'></button>
    <button class='mainbut' id='main8'  onclick='Main(8)'></button>
    <button class='mainbut' id='main9'  onclick='Main(9)'></button>
    <button class='mainbut' id='main10' onclick='Main(10)'></button>
    <button class='mainbut' id='main11' onclick='Main(11)'></button>
</div>
```

and I'd like to create a canvas on top of each one of the same size.  I've tried various things but the canvases either pad the buttons over or all overlap the first button.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why not just make the canvas the button itself? Click the canvas and execute a function?

Comment: Because the canvas drawing functions make drawing a nice button with defined curves at the corners but straight edges a laborious process.  Also vw and vh don't seem to work correctly on canvases.

Comment: I updated my snippet. Not sure what else you were looking for in adding a canvas to a button. If there is something wrong with it let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is something called [CSS Houdini](https://github.com/CSSHoudini/awesome-css-houdini), in particular its [Paint API](https://codersblock.com/blog/say-hello-to-houdini-and-the-css-paint-api/). These are new(ish) standards currently under active development by browsers which allow coders to add a canvas-like background to a wide range of DOM elements - including the <button> element.

The problem with mapping a real canvas to a button is that you need to do a huge amount of work to keep the two in sync (because buttons can have responsive sizes), while at the same time making sure all button-related user events still trigger and bubble correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Yes that looks to be exactly what I want !  What is it with Firefox though ?  I'm having to use Chrome because they haven't implemented WebMIDI yet and it seems the Paint API is again in the distant future at bestNotes
    Marked as “worth prototyping” in Mozilla Standards Positions.

Comment: There is a polyfill which (I believe) works reasonably well - https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/css-paint-polyfill

Comment: Also, my canvas library - Scrawl-canvas - can add canvases to any block-like DOM element. See demo here - https://scrawl-v8.rikweb.org.uk/demo/snippets-004.html - but I think you'll be better off with the Houdini/Paint polyfill solution

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure how efficient this is but you can try something like this to create a canvas for each button and append it.

I didn't feel like messing around with vw/vh so I made each button a fixed size for this demo.

```js
let canvases = [];
let ctx = [];
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

function createCanvas() {
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.left = i * 70 + "px";
    buttons[i].innerHTML = "Button"+(i+1)
    canvases.push(document.createElement("canvas"));
    buttons[i].appendChild(canvases[i]);
    canvases[i].id = "canvas" + i;
    canvases[i].width = buttons[i].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    canvases[i].height = buttons[i].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    ctx[i] = canvases[i].getContext("2d");
    buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+10*i+","+20*i+","+7*i+")";
    
  }
}
createCanvas();

let particleArray = [];
class Particle {
  constructor() {
    this.x = Math.random() * 60;
    this.y = Math.random() * 20;
    this.r = 3;
    this.vx = Math.random() * 3 - 1.5;
    this.vy = Math.random() * 3 - 1.5;
  }
  draw() {
    for (let i = 0; i < ctx.length; i++) {
    ctx[i].fillStyle = "rgb(200,"+20*i+","+30*i+")";
    ctx[i].beginPath();
    ctx[i].arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx[i].fill();
    }
  }
  update() {
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;

    this.draw();
  }
  collision() {
    if (this.x + this.r < 0 || this.x + this.r > 60) {
      this.vx = -this.vx;
      if (this.y + this.r < 0 || this.y + this.r > 20) {
        this.vy = -this.vy;
      }
    }
  }
}

function init() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    particleArray.push(new Particle());
  }
}
init();

function animate() {
  for (let i = 0; i < ctx.length; i++) {
    ctx[i].clearRect(0, 0, 60, 20);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < particleArray.length; i++) {
    particleArray[i].update();
    particleArray[i].collision();
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}
.mainbut {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 0.25vw solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  opacity: 1;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  margin-top: 0vh;
  margin-bottom: 0vh;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px black;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <button class='mainbut' id='main1' onclick='Main(1)'>
  </button>
  <button class='mainbut' id='main2' onclick='Main(2)'></button>
  <button class='mainbut' id='main3' onclick='Main(3)'></button>
  <button class='mainbut' id='main4' onclick='Main(4)'></button>
  <button class='mainbut' id='main5' onclick='Main(5)'></button>
  <button class='mainbut' id='main6' onclick='Main(6)'></button>
  <button class='mainbut' id='main7' onclick='Main(7)'></button>
  <button class='mainbut' id='main8' onclick='Main(8)'></button>
  <button class='mainbut' id='main9' onclick='Main(9)'></button>
  <button class='mainbut' id='main10' onclick='Main(10)'></button>
  <button class='mainbut' id='main11' onclick='Main(11)'></button>
</div>
```